# Is instanceOf broken after Object.create?

Tags: javascript

I tried to do some inheritance with `Object.create` as I usually do. But few days ago I reallized, that `constructor` is also the property of `prototype`, so then my instanced of child appeared like instanced of parent. Well not a big deal, I tried to fix that, here is code snippet:

```
var Parent = function() {
}

var Child = function() {
    Parent.apply(this, arguments);
}

Child.prototype = Object.create(Parent.prototype);
// now I tried to fix that bad constructor
Child.prototype.constructor = Child;
```

Everything was fine:

```
var first = new Child();
first.constructor === Child; // true
first.constructor === Parent; // false
```

then I find out that:

```
first instanceof Child; // true
first instanceof Parent; // true - HUH?!?
```

I mean, this is good, but I dont understand where it happen. **Can anybody explain this?** Thank you

Comment: I think it's because `Parent` is a part of `first`'s prototype chain.

Comment: If Cat inherits from Animal, pussnboots = new Cat() is also an instance of Animal.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript inheritance and the constructor property](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8093057/javascript-inheritance-and-the-constructor-property)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> this is good, but I dont understand where it happen. Can anybody explain this?

The [`instanceof` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof) does not have anything to do with the `.constructor` property - it only checks the prototype chain. Which you correctly did set up with `Object.create`, so that `Parent.prototype.isPrototypeOf(first)`.

Comment: I have another question. Shouldnt be Object.prototype.constructor {writable : false} or {configurable : false} or both? I dont understand, why would anybody want to change this property...

Comment: @Windkiller: It's just [not specified](http://es5.github.io/#x15.2.4). There are hardly good reasons for overwriting built-in objects, but it could be useful if you wanted to [wrap the `Object` constructor](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21243884/1048572).