# Javascript - instantiate an object which it's properties had been modified

Tags: javascript, constructor, prototype, objectinstantiation

Edited:
Say i create a constructor to create my own user-defined objects:

```
var Person = Person(age) { this._age = living; };
```

and i find during runtime that i need to add to the objects that are created by this constructor another property,so i use this to add the property the prototype.

```
Person.prototype.alive;
```

now my only constructor gets only 1 val, is it possible to send that same constructor another val? say something like 
    var newPerson = Person(20,''yes);

Comment: wht you mean by send this class constructor values ?

Comment: Both your question and your example are incomprehensible. You're talking about creating an _object_ and demonstrate it by creating a _constructor_; then you use an undefined variable in said constructor, while disregarding its argument; then you talk about "sending values to this constructor", which means nothing. Consider editing your question and describing your issue more clearly.

Comment: You would need [proxies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy "Proxy - JavaScript | MDN"). Unfortunately they are not implemented in JavaScript yet. What's your use case? I am sure that there must be easier ways to solve your problem.

Comment: You're going to receive the following: `ReferenceError: living is not defined`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> is it possible to send that same constructor another val? say something like `var newPerson = Person(20,'yes');`

No. The constructor you have does only take one parameter.

You can however [redefine the constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21243884/1048572), in your case:

```
Person = (function (original) {
    function Person(age, alive) {
        original.call(this, age);          // apply constructor
        this.alive = alive;                // set new property from new parameter
    }
    Person.prototype = original.prototype; // reset prototype
    Person.prototype.constructor = Person; // fix constructor property
    return Person;
})(Person);
```

Notice that the old object created before this will automagically get assigned new values. You'd need to set them like `oldPerson.alive = 'no';` explicitly for every old instance that you know.

Answer (score 0):

If You consider passing different parameters to constructor, it would be friendlier write constructor to accept single object specifier

```
function Person({paramZ: val, paramX: val})
```