# Issue when trying to inherit all classes referenced by name in a for loop

Tags: javascript, oop, inheritance, subclassing

Well the title is a mouthful but I couldn't come up with a better one, ideas welcome.
Anyhow, I have a javascript object containing classes as properties. I want to create another object which is in every aspect equal to the first one by subclassing it. I'm gonna try to sum it up:

```
var L1 = {};

L1.Foo = function() {/*...*/};
L1.Bar = function() {/*...*/};
//...
L1.Baz = function() {/*...*/};

var L2 = {};

L2.Foo = function() { L1.Foo.call(this); /*possibily some other code here*/ };
L2.Foo.prototype = Object.create(L1.Foo.prototype);
L2.Foo.prototype.constructor = L2.Foo;

L2.Bar = function() { L1.Bar.call(this); /*possibily some other code here*/ };
L2.Bar.prototype = Object.create(L1.Bar.prototype);
L2.Bar.prototype.constructor = L2.Bar;

//...

L2.Baz = function() { L1.Baz.call(this); /*possibily some other code here*/ };
L2.Baz.prototype = Object.create(L1.Baz.prototype);
L2.Baz.prototype.constructor = L2.Baz;

var foo = new L2.Foo();
console.log(foo); //L2.Foo
var bar = new L2.Bar();
console.log(bar); //L2.Bar
var baz = new L2.Baz();
console.log(baz); //L2.Baz
```

[First, working version](http://jsfiddle.net/axedre/jkqayayq/).
I told myself: "huh, looks like there a pattern here" so I went and modified my code as follows:

```
//first 10 lines unaltered

for(prop in L1) {
    L2[prop] = function() { L1[prop].call(this); /*Call super method by default,
    unless overriden below*/ };
    L2[prop].prototype = Object.create(L1[prop].prototype);
    L2[prop].prototype.constructor = L2[prop];
}
//Here I decide that I want to override only the constructor
//for Foo, so naturally:
L2.Foo.prototype.constructor = function() {
    L1.Foo.call(this);
    this.someOtherProperty = "foo";
};

var foo = new L2.Foo();
console.log(foo); //L2.(anonymous function)?
console.log(foo.someOtherProperty); //undefined?
var bar = new L2.Bar();
console.log(bar); //L2.(anonymous function)?
var baz = new L2.Baz();
console.log(baz); //L2.(anonymous function)?
```

[Second, not-so-working version](http://jsfiddle.net/axedre/jkqayayq/2/).
What I am getting wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "huh, looks like there a pattern here" so I went and modified my code
>   as follows:
>
> ```
> for(prop in L1) {
>     L2[prop] = function() { L1[prop].call(this);
> ```

You've hit the common [closure in a loop problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/750486/1048572) - all your `L2` functions are actually calling `L1.Baz` on their new instance as `prop` will have the value `"Baz"`. See the linked question for how to fix this.

Also, notice that none of your constructors does pass its arguments to the super call, which might bite you as well.

---

> Here I decide that I want to override only the constructor for Foo, so
>   naturally:
>
> ```
> L2.Foo.prototype.constructor = function() {
>     L1.Foo.call(this);
>     this.someOtherProperty = "foo";
> };
> ```
>
> What I am getting wrong?

Overwriting the `.constructor` property on a prototype object does *nothing*. Your code is still invoking `new L2.Foo`, not `new L2.Foo.prototype.constructor`. You might want to have a look at [how the `new` keyword works](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1646698/1048572).

Instead, you really need to replace `L2.Foo`. This can be done with [this pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21243884/1048572):

```
L2.Foo = (function (original) {
    function Foo() {
        original.apply(this, arguments);   // apply old L2.Foo constructor
        this.someOtherProperty = "foo";    // set property
    }
    Foo.prototype = original.prototype; // reset prototype
    Foo.prototype.constructor = Foo; // fix constructor property
    return Foo;
})(L2.Foo);
```

(or you just put your standard pattern from the first version). If this does get too repetitive, you might also do the `.prototype` and `.constructor` setup programmatically:

```
// whole code
var L2 = {
    Foo: function() {
        L1.Foo.call(this);
        this.someOtherProperty = "foo";
    }
    // … other overwritten constructors
};
for (var prop in L1) {
    if (!L2[prop]) // unless overridden above, create default that only…
        (function(parent) {
            L2[prop] = function() {
                parent.apply(this, arguments); // calls super
            };
        }(L1[prop]));
    L2[prop].prototype = Object.create(L1[prop].prototype);
    L2[prop].prototype.constructor = L2[prop];
}
```

Comment: Closure in a loop, of course! I feel so dumb, I should know better by now! Thanks for your (thoroughly documented) solution, I will give it a shot over lunch break and hit you back. I'm gonna go ahead and accept it anyway.

Comment: You hit the common "closure in loop" pitfall as well, only noticed now: in anonymous `function(parent) {...}` you still referenced `prop`. I fixed it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jkqayayq/3/) but the problem of `L2.Bar` and `L2.Baz` functions being reported as "anonymous functions" still persists :(
Haven't gone through the links you provided though, they might shine some light. For the time being, thanks.

Comment: Also, I wasn't allowed to edit your post because edits have to be at least 6 characters long, but I believe the brackets around the anonymous function in the `for` loop could should be changed from this form: `(function(parent) {..}(L1[prop]))` to this: `(function(parent) {..})(L1[prop])`.

Comment: I'm only referencing `prop` to assign the new constructor to its place, I'm not using it *inside* the constructor. That you are getting `L2.(anonymous functions)` is not a problem, it is only natural - those functions *are* not named. If you wanted such, have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9479046/1048572). And no, the [parenthesis are correct](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3384504/1048572)

Comment: Indeed, I won't sweat it, and yes you're perfectly right about the closure issue, I had put a `console.log(prop)` *inside* the constructor and it was always logging `Baz`; just outside it, though, it logs `Bar` then `Baz`. Cheers.

Comment: About parenthesis: my bad, again, didn't realize how noob I was till now :) Will read the link you posted to address the anonymous function issue, though I'm thinking of just living with it.

Answer (score 0):

This might just be me, but if the subclass needs to be the same in every aspect as the superclass, why bother making a subclass? I'm not entirely clear an what you are trying to achieve from the code.

But just give the class a property of the class itself
e.g. (in plain java)

```
public class TestInheritClass {

   private TestInheritClass tic;

   public TestInheritClass getTic() {
       return tic;
   }

   public void setTic(TestInheritClass tic) {
        this.tic = tic;
   }    
}
```

Comment: Thanks but not sure how that would work for me in my context, and in javascript.