# JavaScript: Overwrite property defined in constructor for whole class

Tags: javascript

I am trying to overwrite the function of a class:

```
class MyClass {
  constructor() {
    // more code
  }

  myFunction = function() {
    console.log('not this')
  }
}

// can't change the code above

MyClass.prototype.myFunction = function() {
  console.log('it should print this')
}

new MyClass().myFunction()
```

But Babel compiles the above to this:

```
class MyClass {
  constructor() {
    // more code

    this.myFunction = function () {
      console.log('not this');
    };
  }
}

// can't change the code above

MyClass.prototype.myFunction = function () {
  console.log('it should print this');
};

new MyClass().myFunction();
```

Because the function is defined as a property in the original code, Babel puts that definition in the constructor. 
If I understand correctly prototype only contains functions, not all properties. 
Because the constructor runs after the object was derived from the prototype, I can't use the prototype to overwrite that function.

My second try was overwriting the constructor:

```
class MyClass {
  constructor() {
    // more code
  }

  myFunction = function () {
    console.log('not this')
  }
}

// can't change the code above

let oldConstructor = MyClass.prototype.constructor
MyClass.prototype.constructor = function() {
  // call old constructor first, it will set myFunction
  oldConstructor()

  // now overwrite myFunction
  this.myFunction = function () {
    console.log('it should print this')
  }
}

new MyClass().myFunction()
```

Well, let's try...
Compile with Babel, save it to test.js and run:

```
~> node test.js
not this
```

I tried to make the question as general as possible. More background information on why I can't change the class in my specific case: The class is actually from a library I'm using and other packages I use depend on that library too. MeteorJS requires packages to specify the exact version and source of their dependencies, which is why I can't use a fork: I would have to fork every package that depends on this library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact you are changing your class, but it is "not taking" effect because [how javascript interpreter looks for information inside its objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain). First, properties inside object, then prototype chain.

In your first example, if you "remove" local propertie, you change takes effect. Example:

```
class MyClass {
  constructor() {
    // more code

    this.myFunction = function () {
      console.log('not this');
    };
  }
}

// can't change the code above

MyClass.prototype.myFunction = function () {
  console.log('it should print this');
};

const obj = new MyClass();
delete obj.myFunction;
obj.myFunction();
```

https://jsbin.com/gixufadewu/edit?js,console

Comment: This answer was not very helpful in finding a solution, but it is the most helpful answer for understanding the problem and structure.
Since I can't mark my own answer as solution, I'll mark this one as solution because it helped me to understand the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This cannot be done. Whenever you instantiate `MyClass`, the inner `myFunction` is redefined. But not the `myFunction` defined in prototype chain. So the Interpreter will first look for the method in the instance and then in prototype chain. Define your `methods` in prototype chain which can be override with JavaScript [inheritance](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain).

**eg:**

```
var a = new MyClass();
var b = new MyClass();

a.myFunction() === b.myFunction(); //false

a.__proto__.myFunction() === b.__proto__.myFunction() //true
```

Comment: As I said I can't change the original class, but I can override the constructor with inheritance, which is not quite what I was looking for but it works just as well.

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no solution to the original question, I ended up using this:

```
class MyClass {
  myFunction = function() {
    console.log('not this')
  }
}

class MyNewClass extends MyClass {
  myFunction = function() {
    console.log('should print this')
  }
}

new MyNewClass().myFunction()
```

Obviously I always have to use MyNewClass now, which is something I don't really want and the original question asked for a solution to overwrite the function of the existing Class, but this works in my case.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to intercept the assignment by putting a getter/setter on the prototype:

```
function myFunction() {
  console.log('it should print this');
}
Object.defineProperty(MyClass.prototype, "myFunction", {
  set(val) { /* ignore */ },
  get() { return myFunction; }
});
```

Alternatively, you could [decorate the constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21243884/1048572), though for an ES6 class that means [extra precautions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31789308/1048572).