# "Enhance" existing JS class in ECMAScript 2017 (Firefox v55)?

Tags: javascript, class, firefox, ecmascript-2017

Basically I'm wondering whether it is possible to redefine a method at class level, not instance level, as sought [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21243790/is-it-possible-to-redefine-a-javascript-classs-method).

Just to make clear, also, I want to be able to call the original method (on `this`) from within the enhanced/replacement method.

I tried implementing the chosen answer, "decorating the constructor", but it doesn't appear to work in FF55's "SpiderMonkey" version of ES2017: I get a message saying the class "requires new".

Doing a bit of googling I found [this article](https://medium.com/javascript-scene/how-to-fix-the-es6-class-keyword-2d42bb3f4caf). This man talks about a whole bunch of concepts which I wasn't even aware existed in Javascript! My knowledge of JS hasn't gone much beyond the Javascript Definitive Guide 6th Edition, although I do use `Promises` and `async`/`await` a lot (I'm hoping a new edition of the JS Def Guide will come out one day...).

So are there any experts out there who know of a way to, essentially, "enhance" (i.e. re-engineer, not extend) existing JS classes in ES2017?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whoops... thanks to Dovydas for this. I was obviously having a mental block!

```
const superObserve = MutationObserver.prototype.observe;
MutationObserver.prototype.observe = function( target, config ){
    console.log( 'blip');
    superObserve.call( this, target, config );
}
```

Comment: Or of you don't need actual parameters: `MutationObserver.prototype.observe = function( ...args ){
    console.log( 'blip');
    superObserve.call( this, ...args );
}`

Answer (score 0):

Let say you have a class named `Original`, which has a `render` method, which you want to update.

```
class Original {
  render() {
    return 'Original';
  }
}
```

You can update it by changing the `render` method of the prototype of the `Original` function like so:

```
Original.prototype.render = function() {
  return 'Changed';
}
```

If you want to add a new method to your class this is how you do it:

```
Original.prototype.print = function() {
  return 'Printing...';
}
```

Then you can use these methods as usual.

```
const changed = new Original().render();
const printed = new Original().print();
```

Comment: Thanks... but no, that's not what I'm looking for.  I want to replace a class method with an enhanced version of that method and/or add new methods ... to an existing class, so that all new instances will then implement that altered functionality.  My question makes this fairly clear.

Comment: My bad, I didn't understood your problem at first. Updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the update... I also have not made something clear - the fly in the ointment if you will ;-) - I want to be able to call the original method from inside the enhanced method.  I always run into infinite recursion... whereas when overriding on a per-instance basis this is easy to avoid.  Updating the question now...