# Is it possible to hijack / override a class prototype method from a wrapped component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Let's say `App` component is wrapped by bus, which is exported as `withBus`. Here's pseudo-*ish* code.

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {};
  }

  handleSomeEvent(e) {
    this.setState({ [e] });
  }

  render() {
    return ( ... );
  }
}

export default withBus(App);
```

Here, `handleSomeEvent` is defined in the `App` component. It invokes `setState`.

Is it possible for the wrapping component (`withBus`) to hijack / override, App's `setState` instance so that every call to `this.setState` in App is proxied to a method in `withBus` which does some stuff, then invokes setState back on `App`?

**Important Point**

- App shouldn't have to implement anything for this functionality.

---

*In this example, the objective is to add functionality to setState without mudding up react's API.*

Comment: Sure, `withBus` can do anything it wants.

Comment: @Bergi how exactly would you accomplish this? An example would be really helpful please :) Just to be clear.. I don't want to have to say something like `this.setState = withBus.setState` in App.

Comment: You're essentially doing aspect-oriented programming here (read up on that). `withBus` can either modify `App` (e.g. overwrite `setState`) or return a complete new class (resembling the passed `App`) that does whatever you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is perfectly possible:

```
function withBus(C) {
    const orig = C.prototype.setState;
    C.prototype.setState = function() {
        // do whatever you want here
        return orig.apply(this, arguments);
    };
    return C;
}
```

Comment: Gotchas? Many - you have to know what you're doing and what conventions you care about. Also [overwriting things inside the constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21243884/1048572) is considerably more difficult than overwriting prototype methods, [even more so](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31789308/1048572) in ES6.