# How to override a base class constructor in Javascript

Tags: javascript, constructor, overriding, es6-class

The Udacity ES6 training has a question about overriding a base class constructor. I've got a solution but Udacity doesn't let me get away with it.

The assignment is:
Create a Bicycle subclass that extends the Vehicle class. The Bicycle subclass should override Vehicle's constructor function by changing the default values for wheels from 4 to 2 and horn from 'beep beep' to 'honk honk'.

```
class Vehicle {
    constructor(color = 'blue', wheels = 4, horn = 'beep beep') {
        this.color = color;
        this.wheels = wheels;
        this.horn = horn;
    }

    honkHorn() {
        console.log(this.horn);
    }
}

// your code here


/* tests
const myVehicle = new Vehicle();
myVehicle.honkHorn(); // beep beep
const myBike = new Bicycle();
myBike.honkHorn(); // honk honk
*/
```

The solution that I come up with is:

```
class Bicycle extends Vehicle {
    constructor(wheels, horn){
        super(wheels, horn)
        this.wheels = 2
        this.horn = "honk honk" 
    }

    honkHorn(){
        super.honkHorn()
    }

}
```

But that is not good enough And I do not understand why that is. The feedback I got is:

Your Bicycles constructor doesn't set default values for color, wheels, and horn

Comment: I think the exercice is expecting you to set default values for every constructor arguments even in your Bicycle class. Something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/nf570m4k/

Comment: extending the above answer (in your Bicycle) `constructor(wheels = 2, horn = 'tring tring')`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you should not be using

```
    this.wheels = 2
    this.horn = "honk honk"
```

when already overriding these in super constructor.

```js
class Vehicle {
 constructor(color = 'blue', wheels = 4, horn = 'beep beep') {
  this.color = color;
  this.wheels = wheels;
  this.horn = horn;
 }

 honkHorn() {
  console.log(this.horn);
 }
}

class Bicycle extends Vehicle {
 constructor(wheels = 2, horn = 'honk honk') {
  super(undefined, wheels, horn);
 }

 honkHorn() {
  super.honkHorn()
 }

}

let by = new Bicycle();
by.honkHorn();
```

Comment: have you tried removing   ` this.wheels = 2
    this.horn = "honk honk" ` from Bycible constructor. @Edwin

Comment: You should also not set color to be undefined. It will not allow you to submit with color set to undefined. Just use:

`class Bicycle extends Vehicle {
   constructor(color, wheels = 2, horn = "honk honk") {
   super(color, wheels, horn);
 }`

Answer (score 0):

```
class Bicycle extends Vehicle {
    constructor(wheels =2, horn= "honk honk"){
        super(undefined, wheels, horn)
    }

    honkHorn(){
        super.honkHorn()
    }

}
```

then for the test I added:

```
const yourBike = new Bicycle(3, "tring tring")
```

Although other options did provide the right answers for the test cases described in the question. By adding this extra test I found out that overriding a base class constructor is not possible from super nor from this.wheels (as was my first attempt).

However Udacity does not accept it......

Answer (score 0):

```
class Vehicle {
    constructor(color = 'blue', wheels = 4, horn = 'beep beep') {
        this.color = color;
        this.wheels = wheels;
        this.horn = horn;
    }

    honkHorn() {
        console.log(this.horn);
    }
}


class Bicycle extends Vehicle {
    constructor(color,wheels = 2,horn = 'honk honk'){
        super(color,wheels,horn);
    }
}
```

you need not want to call honkHorn() in the child, it automatically calls from the parent.

```
const myVehicle = new Vehicle();
myVehicle.honkHorn(); // beep beep
const myBike = new Bicycle();
myBike.honkHorn(); // honk honk
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).