# TypeScript. How to override parent constructor

Tags: typescript

I'm new in TypeScript. Now I'm learning Classes and get a some question:

When we **extends** parent class we have to use **super()**. But what if I want to omit parent constructor, can we do that or override it?

```js
class Base {
  name: string;
  constructor() {
    name = 'based'
    console.log("Dont show that");
  }
}
 
class Derived extends Base {
  name = "derived";
  constructor(){
    super()
    console.log("My name is " + this.name);
  }
}

const d = new Derived();
```

> [LOG]: "Dont show that"
>
> [LOG]: "My name is derived"

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55760091/how-to-override-a-base-class-constructor-in-javascript) answer your question? this isn't really a typescript particular issue.

Answer (score 0):

> But what if I want to omit parent constructor, can we do that or override it?

No. And further: constructors for derived classes must contain a `super` call.

However, you can design your base class to allow for controlling how the constructor executes based on arguments:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/MYGwhgzhAEBCkFNoG8BQ1oDswFskF5oByAI0SIG5V1pgB7TCAFwCcBXYJul6ACncwB5AA5MAlgzAgAwnQAmCAApgmAC2iFWbBAEoUNDGIBmfASPGSZ8pStV60GR7QYQ6IBADoQdAOa8iACIMTNAQqnQA7tBqKkQ6VE4AvjTJyaigkDABCCxiAG4IctAIAB5MCJhyMPAQSA7QdAUsuQpYuATECrkFcpTUGPSMWpzcfPYGoWzCObxGUrXxE4Ou7l6+vAAGALIAnm140GIwACTIakce2HiJG4sYqdSYCFHZ3YW88dAA9F-QAES7fZII7QLr5Qp-VBPKI1BAfCjfX5-IKYEJhSLRVQqP5AA)

```ts
class Base {
  name = 'base';

  constructor (runOptionalCodePath = true) {
    if (runOptionalCodePath) {
      console.log('Dont show that');
    }
  }
}

class Derived extends Base {
  override name = 'derived';

  constructor () {
    super(false);
    console.log(`My name is ${this.name}`);
  }
}

new Derived(); // "My name is derived"
new Base(); // "Dont show that"
```

Comment: Of course I undrestand we can use some boolean flag, but I thought that there was a built-in ability to disable the execution of the parent constructor.
p.s. If we dont use super how we can work with this?

Comment: @YuriyLukinskikh "_I thought that there was a built-in ability to disable the execution of the parent constructor_": **Why did you think that?** And what would you need to put in the base constructor that you wouldn't want to happen when constructing a derived class? (Whatever it is, that should probably go in a method and not the constructor.)