# Creating Private Methods Using Mixins in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, mixins

My question is pretty straight forward: It is possible to use mixins to create private variables / methods in a JS object? What's the best way to do this? For a decent code example, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17631517/javascript-mixins-when-using-the-module-pattern) question.

Comment: You rather should've [put a bounty](http://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty) or something on that question. I'd be happy to answer there and then close this here as a duplicate.

Comment: done. I look forward to your answer.